# What open source Bluetooth drivers are available for Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

What open source Bluetooth drivers are available for Ubuntu 22.04?

Here is my system configuration:

```
Intel i7 3rd generation
2 core 
16 GB RAM 
Ubuntu 22.04 KDE
Chipset -
Intel Corporation
QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller
```

```
00:00.0 "Host bridge" "Intel Corporation" "3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller" -r09 "Hewlett-Packard Company" "3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller"
00:02.0 "VGA compatible controller" "Intel Corporation" "3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller" -r09 "Hewlett-Packard Company" "3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller"
00:14.0 "USB controller" "Intel Corporation" "7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller" -r04 -p30 "Hewlett-Packard Company" "7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller"
00:16.0 "Communication controller" "Intel Corporation" "7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1" -r04 "Hewlett-Packard Company" "7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller"
00:19.0 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)" -r04 "Hewlett-Packard Company" "82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)"
00:1a.0 "USB controller" "Intel Corporation" "7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2" -r04 -p20 "Hewlett-Packard Company" "7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller"
00:1b.0 "Audio device" "Intel Corporation" "7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller" -r04 "Hewlett-Packard Company" "7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
00:1c.0 "PCI bridge" "Intel Corporation" "7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1" -rc4 "" ""
00:1c.1 "PCI bridge" "Intel Corporation" "7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2" -rc4 "" ""
00:1c.2 "PCI bridge" "Intel Corporation" "7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3" -rc4 "" ""
00:1c.3 "PCI bridge" "Intel Corporation" "7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4" -rc4 "" ""
00:1d.0 "USB controller" "Intel Corporation" "7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1" -r04 -p20 "Hewlett-Packard Company" "7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller"
00:1f.0 "ISA bridge" "Intel Corporation" "QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller" -r04 "Hewlett-Packard Company" "QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller"
00:1f.2 "SATA controller" "Intel Corporation" "7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]" -r04 -p01 "Hewlett-Packard Company" "7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]"
23:00.0 "FireWire (IEEE 1394)" "JMicron Technology Corp." "IEEE 1394 Host Controller" -r30 -p10 "Hewlett-Packard Company" "IEEE 1394 Host Controller"
23:00.1 "System peripheral" "JMicron Technology Corp." "SD/MMC Host Controller" -r30 "Hewlett-Packard Company" "SD/MMC Host Controller"
23:00.2 "SD Host controller" "JMicron Technology Corp." "Standard SD Host Controller" -r30 -p01 "Hewlett-Packard Company" "Standard SD Host Controller"
24:00.0 "Network controller" "Intel Corporation" "Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]" -r34 "Intel Corporation" "Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN"
```

```
lsusb
  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:6310 Microdia Sonix USB 2.0 Camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003d Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS491
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i blue

[  292.799848] audit: type=1107 audit(1651248816.850:70): pid=772 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=2653 label="snap.prospect-mail.prospect-mail"
[  292.935764] audit: type=1107 audit(1651248816.986:72): pid=772 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=2710 label="snap.teams-for-linux.teams-for-linux"
```

Comment: `lspci -m`would be better, since we need to know your chips, not your cpu. Copy the output of the terminal and paste it into your question.

Comment: Intel Corporation QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller

Comment: We need all the lines. I don't think this will suffice. If you have problems formatting it, we'll help ;-)

Comment: If it is actually a 6205 wifi device, it did not have the bluetooth built in but the 6235 did

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth drivers are integrated into the Linux kernel. Except some exotic cases I've never came across, you don't need any drivers for Bluetooth.

However vendor firmware (proprietary) is often needed. It is included in `linux-firmware` package. For some hardware it is not included yet. Then you may need to install it.

In your case you seem to have an Intel Wi-Fi+ BT device. Firmware should be there. If the Bluetooth isn't working for some reason, you can find the reason by running these commands:

```
lsusb
dmesg | grep -i blue
```

If you post output of these commands to your question, it will make possible some assistance.